# How I can auto increment each class objects?

Tags: c++, class, static, private, increment

I have a class that contain two private int , one is const (m_id) and the other one is static (next_id).

I want to set m_id to next_id and increment next_id each time I create an object of the class.

But since it's a const I can't set it like that :

```
Class::Class() 
{
m_id = next_id++;
}
```

I need to set it like that

```
Class::Class() :m_id(next_id)
{
next_id++;
}
```

But that's not good either because I can't access private static like that.

Someone told me that const is not intented to be used for that, so to simply remove it. Is that really the only solution?

edit : here the full header and source

header

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H_LEA12OED
#define ENTITY_H_LEA12OED

#include "EntityKey.h"
#include "ComponentManager.h"
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity ();
    virtual ~Entity ();

private:
    ekey m_key; 
    ComponentManager m_componentManager;
    const int m_id;
    static int next_id;
};

#endif /* end of include guard: ENTITY_H_LEA12OED */
```

source

```
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity() :m_id(next_id++)
{

}

Entity::~Entity()
{
}
```

(of course EntityKey and ComponentManager doesn't have anything to do with my question)

(edit 2: corrected some errors in the code due to testing)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't access private static like that"? Maybe you should post a complete code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `next_id`, or else it will compile, **but not link**. Like so:

```
class Class
{
    /* whatever */
};

Class::Class() :m_id(next_id++)
{
    /* whatever */
}

int Class::next_id = 0;
```

Comment: thanks that was that (the declaration of next_id to 0), didn't think that would cause that